# How to Connect to local mysql server while working on remote files?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a situation where i'm working on the remote files through ssh, but for testing purpose i want to configure that to connect to my local mysql server.

we can't give the host as 'localhost' as it will always refer the remote server in this case. And i can't either give my local ip... How it can be done?

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that i need this configuration to be done in a php config file so that the application runs using my local database.

Comment: Why not just dump your local database, import it on the server and test it there?

Comment: The server has its own database. I dont want to mess up with data there.. So i want to use the local database. And i don't have permission to create/add a new database in server

Answer (score 2):

If there is an instance of MySQL on the remote you need to map a different port for your MySQL instance:

```
ssh -C -4 -R 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 remote.host
```

Change the url for the MySQL connection on the remote to use port 13306 instead of 3306.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot reach the server directly (using IP) try configuring a SSH tunnel.

See:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/
- http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/133/Tunnel+local+MySQL+server+through+SSH#gs

Answer (score 0):

Use a `%` character in hostname for MySQL user.